I would like to use 'texttalk/websocket' in my laravel project
I would like to use 'texttalk/websocket (https://packagist.org/packages/textalk/websocket)' ' in my laravel project.
The package is currently installed using the 'composer require texttalk/websocket' command.
How do I use that package in my controller?
composer require texttalk/websocket
-> install texttalk/websocket

Are you trying to use the client or the server component in your project?

fyi: "This project has been archived and is no longer maintained."

This library has been replaced by https://github.com/sirn-se/websocket-php

Add more details to your question to help us understand what you are trying to achieve.

Basic example for client
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function websocket()
    {
        $client = new \WebSocket\Client("wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw");
        $client->text("Hello WebSocket.org!");
        echo $client->receive();
        $client->close();
    }
}

